# how to use preferences in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to save a username for game in preferences (first time user enters the game, registration screen shows up, and after that whenever user enters the game, username is automatically synchronized).

i tried the following

`// in create() method of game class
   userPreferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences("userPrefs");`

then, in my registration stage

`enter.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                super.clicked(event, x, y);
                user.username = usernameField.getText();
                PanBallGame.getGameInstance().userPreferences.putString("username", user.username);
                user.requestPath = "/addUser";
                new RequestObserver(user);
            }
        });`

but this doesn't save the username in preferences.
Can anyone explain how to get this work ? Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing flush command after put command.

```
public class GameManager {
  private static final String RESULT_BEST = "BEST_RESULT";
  public String userID;
  private Preferences PREFS;
  public static final GameManager INSTANCE = new GameManager();
  int result;
  //...
  private GameManager() {
    PREFS = Gdx.app.getPreferences(GameManager.class.getSimpleName());
    userID = "XXXX";
  }

  public void setBestResult(int result) {
    PREFS.putInteger(RESULT_BEST, result);
    PREFS.flush();  //THIS IS MISSING
  }

 public int getBestResult() {
    return PREFS.getInteger(RESULT_BEST, 0);
 }
```

}